# After packaging an electron app (installed with -no--asar) child_process.spawn not working

Tags: electron, child-process, electron-packager, asar

I know that running a bin file with spawn doesn't work when packaging an electron app with asar on a mac.
To go around that I run electron-packager with -no--asar and the app spawns processes just fine. Everything dies after running the installer?

```
electron-packager . --overwrite -no--asar --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=./app/assets/icons/mac/1024.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds
```

The app runs fine, then:

```
electron-installer-dmg release-builds/simple-darwin-x64/simple.app/ simple-app
```

the child_spawn.('./bin') is dead...

I hate macs... Of course everything works on linux
Thanks!